# how does scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue 's ordering work?

Tags: scala, data-structures

```
implicit val ord:Ordering[String] = Ordering.by(_.length)
var nameQueue = new PriorityQueue[String]()
nameQueue.+=("SINES","YINE","WIRAEUS")
nameQueue.foreach(println)
```

and the output is:

```
WIRAEUS
YINE
SINES
```

This seems confusing. Can anybody help explain the ordering's mechanism?

Comment: so how do you want them to order, or you want to understand why the ordering like the one above ?

Comment: i want the elements to be ordered by its length in descending

Comment: so your method is doing that part, look at the answer below , if you call dequeue method on ur priority queue you will get ur answer in the order which you want.

Comment: So because ur data structure has 3 elements, so you have to call dequeue method thrice on ur data structure and dequeue will return a string, so you can print and see the output.

Comment: ok. Thank you all

Answer (score 5):

From the `PriorityQueue` [ScalaDocs page](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/PriorityQueue.html).

> Only the **dequeue** and **dequeueAll** methods will return elements in priority order (while removing elements from the heap). Standard collection methods including **drop**, **iterator**, and **toString** will remove or traverse the heap in whichever order seems most convenient.
>
> Therefore, printing a **PriorityQueue** will not reveal the priority order of the elements, though the highest-priority element will be printed first.